# Visual Studio Code Live server injects a white div to the bottom of the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciyJv.png - White DIV on the website.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHwJX.png - White DIV code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZraZI.png - No such code in HTML.

The white DIV is injected by live server AND it goes over to the website hosted by DNS.

https://www.kristotanak.ee

How do I get rid of it? I am a 16 year old student studying software development soo please don't bully me.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: How do you know that's a DIV?

Comment: try giving your `body` a style of `height: 100vh`. check if the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your css file :

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have ended there.
The white  you claim is being displayed is by default the background-color of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's a div with an iframe inside, for me works this code in the css

```
div iframe {
   display: none;
}
```